# Python - Packing string representing short int into 2 byte string

Tags: python, string, byte, pack

I do some sort of calculation and in the end I have an int that needs at most 16 bits to represent. I want to pack it into a string in unsigned short int format. For example, if I have 1223, I want to store 0000010011000111. 
I tried using:

```
n = pack('H', 1223)
```

When I tried to print in (in binary representation) I got:

```
11000111 100
```

But I want the leading zeros to also be encoded into n, how can I do it elegantly?

Comment: How are you printing it?

Comment: ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in n)

Comment: @enemypower4 Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but why not just use `format(3, '08b')`

Comment: To be crystal clear: there is no such thing as a Python string that is "2 bytes." In Python 3, `sys.getsizeof('')` returns 25 bytes! Leading 0's are part of the string representation and have nothing to do with the underlying data...you need to specify what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @brianpck, I thought that the OP asked how to represent 16 bits as a string - otherwise you are right